# How to open an image at a URL with Intervention

Tags: php, lumen, intervention

I'm trying to open an image with [Intervention](http://image.intervention.io/)

```
use Intervention\Image\ImageManagerStatic as Image;

$image = Image::make('https://via.placeholder.com/300/09f/fff.png');
```

but when dumping it, there is just null returned.

If I dd the actual image

```
dd(file_get_contents('https://via.placeholder.com/300/09f/fff.png'));
```

I see

```
b"ëPNG\r\n\x1A\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x01,\x00\x00\x01,\x04\x03\x00\x00\x00ïSôF\x00\x00\x00\ePLTE\x00Ö    ▀‗ ƒÏ \x1FÑ \x7F╠ ┐Õ _┐ ?▓ ¹\\t\r\x00\x00\x03¸IDATx ▶"
```

I've tried

```
 $image = Image::make(file_get_contents('https://via.placeholder.com/300/09f/fff.png'));
```

But dd($image) also returns null.

I also tried

```
private function get_content($URL){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
$image = Image::make($this->get_content('https://via.placeholder.com/300/09f/fff.png'));
```

dd($image) returns null for that too.

Do you have any ideas on how I can open the image with this library? I'm using Lumen, and have tried to run it using both Docker and php artisan serve.

Could it be anything to do with Composer?

**Update**

I also wondered whether it might be due to the driver. Gd is the default one for Image Intervention. I made sure that and imagick are enabled in the php.ini and tried both gd (default) and imagick as drivers

```
Image::configure(['driver' => 'imagick']);
```

but dd($image) stays null.

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFYDy.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ruw4.png

Also, checking storage/logs/laravel.log does not show anything.

**Final Update**

The solution turned out to be related to composer. I deleted the composer.lock and the vendors contents and performed a fresh composer install and $image now shows the required data.

Comment: `allow_url_fopen` is a setting in your php.ini, not a function. Can you actually access that URL at all? Just do a `var_dump(file_get_contents('url-to-the-file'));` and see what you get back before you try and pass it into some other function.

Comment: @Magnus Corrected, thanks for that.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I've updated the post with the dump of the file_get_contents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Image::make(file_get_contents('https://via.placeholder.com/300/09f/fff.png')` returns the `Image` object.

So you can return the image with `->response()`.

```php
use Intervention\Image\ImageManagerStatic as Image;

Route::get('/test', function() {
    return Image::make(file_get_contents('https://via.placeholder.com/300/09f/fff.png'))->response();
});
```

Comment: That returns null for me when I run it.

`Call to a member function response() on null`

Comment: Perhaps you should dump the value of ```file_get_contents('https://via.placeholder.com/300/09f/fff.png')``` @X__

Comment: @Ballard I did that in the post above.

Comment: `file_get_contents` may be disabled in your php.ini ? It's often the case on shared host. You can still use curl though.

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier But you can see in my original post that it is outputting some data so file_get_contents is working. And I've also shown curl within the make method of Image, and the make method returns null for that too.

Comment: So, after you did `$image = Image::make(file_get..)` and you do `dd($image)`, the content of `dd()` is null as well?

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier Yes that's where I am finding out the result. Always by using dd

Comment: I don't have Lumen, I have Laravel, but it shouldn't interfere as `Intervention` and `file_get_content` as nothing related. Can you add the version of the library? For reference: https://i.imgur.com/lxOQQNt.png It totally works for me.

Comment: Thinking of, could it be an issue with `GD` or `Imagick` driver? Another option would be to re-install the vendors in case a search and replace has gone wrong.

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier the version is 2.5.1. I have updated the question with checks on the drivers. But I think the driver could be a way forward, I just can't see anything relevant yet.

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier 're-install the vendors', what do you mean here? I'm going to assume you mean composer.

Comment: I mean, delete the `vendors` directory and run `composer install` to re-install them. But you figured it out :)